# Error with strcat in C

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to use strcat function to manipulate the strings in linux but it throws me an error. I have no idea why.. Here is the code

```
int YX = 1234;
char YX2[100];
sprintf(YX2, "%d", YX);  //converting int to str
char str[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
strcat(YX2, str[4]);

//snprintf(YX2, sizeof(YX2), "%s%s", str[4])  <- this one won't work neither
```

The system just crash after this...

Comment: The code doesn't compile as written - str[4] is of type char (value 5, the last number in the array), but strcat requires a null terminated string.

Comment: in addition, `str` will not contain characters `1` etc. but the ASCII values (non-printable characters at that end of the table)

Comment: @LeeTaylor; Yes. But, this will not throw any error.

Comment: @haccks of course, just pointing out another flaw of the code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out :p

Comment: @james please do not correct your question (`char str[5]`) in response to comments unless you posted it wrongly. Either that was your code, or it wasn't.

Comment: Probably you have warning message for line 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both arguments of `strcat` should be pointer to null terminated `char` strings (`char *` type). `str[4]` is of `char` type.

Comment: how about i store that str[4] value into another char value called 'c1' and do strcat(YX2, c1). but still throws me an error?

Comment: @james You still need to terminate your strings will null. if they don't have null then c routines do not know where the end of the strings are. This is what causes your program to crash.

Comment: @james ...and `c1` is still `char`. The function `strcat` needs two 0-terminated strings, as already remarked.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a char as if it is a char *. The pointer str is "12345" while str[4] is the character '5'.

strcat receives two arguments (char *, char *) 
while you are sending         (char *, char).

I am not 100 percent what you are trying to do so I will give you two answers.

strcat(YX2, str);
This will give you the string "123412345"

Or:

YX2[4] = str[4]; or YX2[strlen(YX2)] = str[4];
Both of these will add the character to the end.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change strcat to `strcat( YX2, str + 4 )`. When you put `str[4]` as parameter 2, its value is '5' which is converted to pointer and copy is started from address 0x00035 in memory... which is not what you want;
2. Change definition to `char str[6] = {'1','2','3','4','5', 0}`, `char str[6] = "12345"` or `char str[] = "12345"`. In your case there is no 0 at end of string and `strcat` copies until 0.